# Filtrar CSV desde ComboBox

Tags: c#, csv, combobox, filtro, textbox

primero que nada estoy iniciando en la programación.

Tengo un archivo CSV que tiene una base de datos delimitada por (,):

Ej:

Dato1, Dato2, Dato3, Dato4, Dato5, Etc....

Dato1, Dato2, Dato3, Dato4, Dato5, Etc....

Dato1, Dato2, Dato3, Dato4, Dato5, Etc....

Dato1, Dato2, Dato3, Dato4, Dato5, Etc....

La idea es que los Datos 1,2 aparezcan en un ComboBox para filtrar la informacion y que los demas datos aparezcan en diferentes TextBox. Hasta ahora solo he conseguido que aparezcan los datos 1 y 2 en el ComboBox con el siguiente codigo:

```
       string[] Datos = File.ReadAllLines("./Hoja4.csv");
        foreach (var Data in Datos)
        {
            var valores = Data.Split(',');
            CbLocalidad.Items.Add(valores[0] + " " + valores[1]);

                 }
```

Quiero filtrar la fila por el ComboBox y que los textbox se llenen con la demas informacion de esa fila.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Según lo que dices quieres llenar 1 combo con una lista de: Columna1 + Columna2, y cuales son los textos? estas utilizando Windows forms?, yo te sugiero que primero crees una entidad o un modelo de datos y pases todos esos datos del CSV a la entidad, después trabajes con ese objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Hice un ejemplo:

> CSV utilizado para el ejemplo:

```
A, Dato2, ADato3, ADato4, ADato5
B, Dato2, BDato3, BDato4, BDato5
C, Dato2, CDato3, CDato4, CDato5
D, Dato2, DDato3, DDato4, DDato5
```

> Cree un objeto para pasar los datos del CSV

```
public class CsvDatos
{
    public int Renglon { get; set; }
    public string ComboDisplayMember { get; set; }
    public string Columna3 { get; set; }
    public string Columna4 { get; set; }
    public string Columna5 { get; set; }
}
```

> Para pasar los datos del CSV al combo, primero habia que convertir CSV al objeto que cree

```
        string[] datos = File.ReadAllLines(this.textBox1.Text);
        List<CsvDatos> csvDatos = new List<CsvDatos>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var renglon in datos)
        {
            i++;
            var valores = renglon.Split(',');
            csvDatos.Add(new CsvDatos()
            {
                Renglon = i,
                ComboDisplayMember = valores[0] + " " + valores[1],
                Columna3 = valores[2],
                Columna4 = valores[3],
                Columna5 = valores[4]
            });
        }

        this.comboBox1.DataSource = csvDatos;
        this.comboBox1.ValueMember = nameof(CsvDatos.Renglon);
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(CsvDatos.ComboDisplayMember);
```

> Este es el diseño del formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Es necesario agregar un evento al Combo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En el evento del combo solo hay que tomar el `objeto` actual seleccionado y tomar de este objeto los datos que serán mostrados en los `textbox`

```
        var csvRenglon = (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem as CsvDatos);
        MostrarDato(csvRenglon);
```

> Este seria el código  del form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CsvDatos
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] datos = File.ReadAllLines(this.textBox1.Text);
            List<CsvDatos> csvDatos = new List<CsvDatos>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var renglon in datos)
            {
                i++;
                var valores = renglon.Split(',');
                csvDatos.Add(new CsvDatos()
                {
                    Renglon = i,
                    ComboDisplayMember = valores[0] + " " + valores[1],
                    Columna3 = valores[2],
                    Columna4 = valores[3],
                    Columna5 = valores[4]
                });
            }

            this.comboBox1.DataSource = csvDatos;
            this.comboBox1.ValueMember = nameof(CsvDatos.Renglon);
            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = nameof(CsvDatos.ComboDisplayMember);
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LimpiarDatos();
            var csvRenglon = (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem as CsvDatos);
            MostrarDato(csvRenglon);
        }

        private void MostrarDato(CsvDatos csvDato)
        {
            this.txtDato3.Text = csvDato.Columna3;
            this.txtDato4.Text = csvDato.Columna4;
            this.txtDato5.Text = csvDato.Columna5;
        }

        private void LimpiarDatos()
        {
            this.txtDato3.Text = string.Empty;
            this.txtDato4.Text = string.Empty;
            this.txtDato5.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

> El resultado se vería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono